# Controller is missing a template for request formats: text/html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

Based on all the other threads I've read, this is typically because the view isn't in the expected location. But I've gone through my directory a number of times, checked my controller and routes files, and AFAIK, everything seems in order.

Here's the error: `PagesController#index is missing a template for request formats: text/html`

Here's a screenshot of my directory and my `Routes` file:
[image]

Here's my `Pages` controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end
end
```

I have a feeling there is something very obvious that I'm missing...

Comment: Try restarting the server if is running or to stop Spring (`spring stop`).

Comment: @SebastianPalma I've tried starting and stopping a couple times. No luck.

Comment: You can add the whole stacktrace of the error in your logs to the question.

Comment: I just started over with a new app and I no longer see the issue. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on a site I am building. The funny or strange thing is that when stopped working last night everything worked fine, and I could see all the pages on my site. But when I started the server this morning - 5 hours later - I got an error similar to yours.

The only change in my environment was that I used **Windows PowerShell** to start the rails server. So I switched to Command Prompt, and promptly got another error message - something to the effect that the server was still running. I deleted this file >>> 
 **/tmp/pis/server.pid** and reran the server, et voila! everything worked like before. Interesting enough I do have **Powershell Core (the cross-platform PS)** installed, and it also does not give me any problem at all.Is it something to do with **Windows Powershell**? I don't know, it just solved my issue for me.

Comment: I was using Mac, but I did take a different approach when I started over. Instead of manually creating the files, I ran `rails g controller`. Not sure if that actually had something to do with it, but it worked.